# Getting record against nearest coming date for each distinct PID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `active` and data in table is as following.. **Sample Data**

```
id     pid     chq_date
-------------------------
1      6       2013-07-07
2      4       2013-10-06
3      4       2013-07-06
4      5       2013-01-06
5      13      2013-09-16
6      33      2013-09-08
7      4       2013-02-06
8      13      2013-01-06
9      7       2013-07-06
10     4       2013-08-02
```

I need to get records of nearest coming date for each distinct pid **Desired output from sample data** is

```
id     pid     chq_date
-------------------------
1      6       2013-07-07
3      4       2013-07-06
5      13      2013-09-16
6      33      2013-09-08
9      7       2013-07-06
```

I have tried different queries but did not get desired result. The query which seems me nearest is

```
 select * from active where chq_date>=sysdate and chq_date in (select 
 min(chq_date) from active where pid in (select distinct pid from active))
```

[**Fiddle Link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a28cc/7)

Comment: but the pid 4 seems to have 2 rows.. How is it distinct

Comment: Min (coming) date aginst 4 is 2013-07-06

Comment: So change your desired output

Comment: and what about the row `4      5       2013-01-06` where pid is 5

Comment: That date is past... I need only coming dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some changes in sashkello's answer as group by can not be used that way so I used it in inner query

```
select * from active where chq_date in (SELECT MIN(chq_date)
FROM active WHERE chq_date >= SYSDATE GROUP BY pid)
```

[**Fiddle Link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a28cc/8)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    pid, 
    MIN(IF(chq_date > SYSDATE, chq_date, NULL)) 
FROM active 
GROUP BY pid
```

Or if you want to remove `pid`s which don't have upcoming dates:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    pid, 
    MIN(chq_date) 
FROM active
WHERE chq_date > SYSDATE
GROUP BY pid
```

Comment: sorry i tagged it wrongly.. its oracle so I have changed Now() to sysdate but interval still needs to be changed someway..

Comment: Changed to add_months, but I still think INTERVAL should work in Oracle?.. or not?...

Comment: Actually, doesn't matter - NULL should be OK, this should be much more universal solution.